# Converting an empty string into nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean, string

I have a string called `word` and a function called `infinitive` such that
`word.infinitive` would return another string on some occasions and an empty string otherwise
I am trying to find an elegant ruby one line expression for the code-snippet below

```
if word.infinitive == ""
      return word
else return word.infinitive
```

Had infinitive returned nil instead of "", I could have done something like

```
(word.infinitive or word)
```

But since it does not, I can't take advantage of the short-circuit OR
Ideally I would want
1) a single expression that I could easily embed in other code
2) the function infinitive being called only once
3) to not add any custom gems or plugins into my code

Comment: Note that "or" and || do the same thing, but || has much higher precedence

Comment: in other words, they both short-circuit, is what I was trying to say

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not ashamed of monkeypatching and abusing syntax, this would work:

```
class String
  def | x
    if empty? then x else self end
  end
end
```

Then you can say `word.infinitive | word`, which actually scans fairly naturally, if you ask me.

However, I think a better idea would be to modify the infinitive method, or add a version of it that returns the word unchanged.

*Edit:* Here's a possibly more elegant solution:

```
[word.infinitive, word].find {|x| not x.empty?}
```

Comment: That's clever, but the OP sounds like he's leaning towards something minimally invasive.

Comment: this is invasive... but considering the fact that I have to do something like this on multiple occasions, its a pretty useful trick.. can't imagine how this would screw up any code in other places.. thanks

Comment: @adi92 I would really suggest rewriting the infinitive method if you could.

Comment: its part of a package my code is importing..  
other people's code also use those packages..  
so modifying infinitive is not really an option.

Comment: `((vv=<something>)!='' || nil) && vv` turns <something> into nil if its value is ''

Comment: Downvoted. This is a terrible solution compared to the answer below it.

Answer (score 129):

The ActiveSupport [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence) method converts an empty (or `blank?`) string to `nil`.  It's designed for your exact use case:

```
word.infinitive.presence || word
```

Note that you can easily use ActiveSupport outside of rails:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```

Comment: @Intrepidd I can't either, so I'll upvote your comment instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a regex like [this article suggests](http://rors.org/2008/3/19/self-or-default-if-empty-dry-way)

```
(word.infinitive[/.+/m] or word) #Fancy way to convert "" to nil
```

Answer (score 6):

Do the right thing - fix infinitive so that it returns nils instead of blank strings, or wrap it with your own interface if you really can't touch it.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can monkeypatch a new function to String without having to abuse syntax.

```
class String
  def squash
    self.empty? ? nil : self
  end
end
```

Now you can do

```
puts var.squash or "default text"
```

I'm not a native english speaker so I don't know if *squash* is the best word. Is there a word that would better convey the idea of "turn into nil only if empty"?

Comment: I like it, I think I'll be using this some:

class String
  def nillify
    self.empty? ? nil : self
  end
end

"".nillify or "foo"
=> "foo"

Comment: @DGM I named it `to_nil`, although it doesn't change non-empty strings.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ternary operator `(boolean ? true-val : false-val)` with `String#empty?`

```
return word.infinitive.empty? ? word : word.infinitive
```

if you only want to call infinitive once:

```
return (inf = word.infinitive).empty? ? word : inf
```

You may also want to consider adding some [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to your code.