# Rails ||= for empty strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code won't change the variable:

```rb
@my_var = ''
@my_var ||= 'This is a non-empty string'
```

Is there any nice/clean way to do this so that empty strings are overwritten?

Comment: Here, `@my_var` in not null. So, you've to do something like this: `@my_var = 'This is a non-empty string' if @my_var.empty?` or `@my_var = 'This is a non-empty string' unless @my_var.present?`

Comment: monkey patching can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647370/converting-an-empty-string-into-nil-in-ruby

Comment: monkey-patching may cause you grief.

Comment: Other way you can set value as `nil` instead of `''`(blank string) like => `@my_var = ''.presence
@my_var ||= 'This is a non-empty string'`

Comment: If `@my_var` is undefined / not set, you should avoid empty string and just use `nil` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
@my_var = ''
@my_var = @my_var.presence || 'This is a non-empty string'
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: I didn't know that,  great tip!

Answer (score 1):

in this case, i would just check the length of this string:

```
@my_var = ''
@my_var = 'This is a non-empty string' if @my_var.length == 0
=> "This is a non-empty string"
```